# React Native - error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: java, android, react-native

React Native throws these errors when compiling...

MainActivity.java:26:

MainActivity.java:35:

error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

How should these two functions be changed?

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {


@Override
protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
}


@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new BeaconsAndroidPackage()
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what version of RN are you using? getUseDeveloperSupport method uses public access modifier since RN 0.40

Also MainActivity looks different from what you have in latest version. Take a look here: https://github.com/ncuillery/rn-diff/tree/8ef420bed9e3d0b091aa6b6a630616a51f8460d6/RnDiffApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/rndiffapp

It's a `react-native init` setup. You can just copy and paste what they have and add your packages to `getPacakges` list.

Comment: You can also use react-native-git-upgrade: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/react-native-git-upgrade though I personally never had any luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just need to comment out the @Override decorator in MainActivity.java and it should work fine. Try it.